# Unable to run integration test without compiling (with failsafe)

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I currently try to run an integration test with maven failsafe, like described in here: [reference link](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) .

For this, I got 3 Modules: datamodule, datamodule2 and testmodule (all covered by a parent pom). testmodule depends on the two other modules. It got an test in src/test/java/ named MyTestIT.java. If I try to run the test with `mvn clean test failsafe:integration-test`, everything runs fine, but if I only run `mvn failsafe:integration-test`, it does not work. Does somebody know how it's this way?

If I try to run the test with surefire, for example with `mvn test -Dtest=MyTestIT`, it says it can't find MyTestIT in datamodule, and I need to set `-DfailIfNoTests=false`. If I try to run it with `mvn test --pl testmodule`, it says it can't find the dependencies (this only happens when they are not installed, but I don't want to call install everytime I run a test).

Is there any way of setting this in a pom, either in the parent pom or in the project pom? Or any other way of saying to maven "only run the integration tests, use the right dependencies and do not install everything"?

Comment: have you tried `mvn verify`?

Comment: Yes, `mvn verify` works, but also runs the unit tests before, and thats exactly the behaviour I do not want. I want only the integration tests to run.